# What's a dark colored python editor that has printing?

Tags: python, dark-theme

I'd like to print to onenote and annotate the code.

Let's exclude Sublime Text printing solutions because sadly after spending a few hours, I realized that I am too dumb to figure those solutions out.

What dark colored python editor can I use?

Comment: What is a dark colored python editor? Why is it important? Do you want to print white on black? What has printing to OneNote have to do with dark colors?

Comment: Just about all of them. I can't concieve of an editor that doens't allow printing, and most seem to be themeable.

Comment: Btw, you relaly mean `editor`, or do you mean `IDE`? How do you plan to debug?

Comment: Plus the usual questions about which o/s, must it be gratis (even for commerical use), etc, etc? You really haven't giving us much to go on here. Why not just point a shotgun at Gogole? Whatever you hit probably meets your (stated) requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt, the most full featured Python IDE is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

It is also cross platform and free (since you forgot to state your requirements on these topics).

Yes, it has a dark theme:

[image]

And, yes, it can print. Check out the full list of [features](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/).

No offense, but htis is the worst question that I have seen on Stack Overflow in a long, long time. Couldn't you just have goggled?

1. dark
2. can print

That's ***really*** it? Surely we can help you more than that? But you have to help us, we can't read your mind.

Is code completion important to you? Refactoring? A good debugger? Integration with Version Control? Anything else?

We can help you with all of that, and much more, if you would only read ask. Because I still can't bring myself to believe that you wanted only those two points and preferred to ask us rather than Google.

Answer (score 0):

The dark-colored theme exists in [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/), but it has limited printing: you need to export file to HTML page (File - Export to HTML) and then print (if you want) this page. Not sure what OneNote must do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Windows, in which case the obvious choice is Notepad++, which has a solid print feature built in.

Although the default Notepad++ theme has an all-white background, you can easily change the theme to one that has a dark background.